# Quarkus - how to provide java params to running app from maven runner?

Tags: quarkus

When running:

```
mvn quarkus:dev
```

How can I provide params to jvm? I am looking for something similar to spring:

```
-Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

or older:

```
-Drun.jvmArguments="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8"
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is correct. Otherwise I cannot mark another one as a duplicate of this one. It is also a matter of courtesy to give feedback to the person who answered the question and it helps keep SO clean. Your question is still listed as unanswered.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `jvm.args` property from command line:

```sh
mvn quarkus:dev -Djvm.args=...
```

Or specify the same in Maven's parameters:

```xml
<project ...>
    ...
    <properties>
        <jvm.args>-Dquarkus.datasource.url=...</jvm.args>
    </properties>
    ...
</project>
```

Or through the `jvmArgs` property of the plugin:

```xml
<project ...>
    ...
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>dev</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>...</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jvmArgs>-Dquarkus.datasource.url=...</jvmArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

Comment: Don't miss the `quarkus-maven-plugin` like me ... I lost half a day for that