# How to set a specific timezone when executing quarkus:dev?

Tags: quarkus

I am newbie on Quarkus.
For testing/dev purpose, I need to set a specific TZ when running quarkus:dev. I dont want to touch the code, nor changing the OS TZ. Only conf/prop should be used.

Googling a lot but no solution found.

env : quarkus 2.16 / intellj / jdk11

Thanks in advance.

Comment: found :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61999914/quarkus-how-to-provide-java-params-to-running-app-from-maven-runner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Java based programs can accept a command line argument to set the timezone like `-Duser.timezone="America/New_York"` so something like:

```
mvn -Duser.timezone="America/New_York" quarkus:dev
```

works for me.